# calculating network days, with some dates omitted from exceptions - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

The following is a macro which collects data from data we import into certain tabs. When the macro is run it filters through the data and produces a new excel book with this new data. The person who created this is no longer with us. The macro works fine except I'm trying to add another column like the one that calculates network days called days since 1st auth less parked. Im wanting to add another which gives days since the start of the information being passed to us. Ie a column call 1st instructed less parked.

```
Sub Runme()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Macro recorded 22/03/2013'

'
    Sheets("CCX data SORTED").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Sheets("CCX Data Raw").Select
    Range("A:C,E:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("H2").Select
    Range("A1:X10000").Sort Key1:=Range("H1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    Range("H55000").End(xlUp)(2, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CCX data SORTED").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("CCX Data Raw").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Sheets("CCX data SORTED").Select
    Columns("X:X").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("X2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-23],'SCMT weekly data'!C[-17]:C[-11],7,FALSE)>0,(VLOOKUP(RC[-23],'SCMT weekly data'!C[-17]:C[-11],7,FALSE)),"""")"
    Range("X2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("X2:X5000")
    Range("X1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SCMT end Date"
    Columns("X:X").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("SCMT Weekly data").Select
    Columns("Z:Z").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("Z1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Days To Exclude 1"
    Range("Z2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNTA(RC[-2],RC[-1])=2,NETWORKDAYS(RC[-2],RC[-1],'Bank hols'!RC[-25]:R[56]C[-25]),0)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Z2:Z5000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Columns("AD:AD").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("AD1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Days To Exclude 2"
    Range("AD2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNTA(RC[-2],RC[-1])=2,NETWORKDAYS(RC[-2],RC[-1],'Bank hols'!RC[-29]:R[56]C[-29]),0)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AD2:AD5000")
    Columns("Z:Z").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Columns("AD:AD").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Range("AH2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    Range("AF1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Days since first auth"
    Range("AF2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNTA(RC[-21],R2C34)=2,NETWORKDAYS(RC[-21],R2C34,'Bank hols'!RC[-31]:R[56]C[-31]),"""")"
    Range("AG2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-1]),SUM(RC[-1]-(RC[-3]+RC[-7])),"""")"
    Range("AG1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Days since 1st Auth less parked"
    Columns("AH:AH").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("AH1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Still Parked"
    Range("AH2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[-10]),ISBLANK(RC[-9])),""XX"",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[-6]),ISBLANK(RC[-5])),""XX"",""""))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AH2:AH5000")
    Range("AF2:AG2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AF2:AG5000")
    Range("A55000").End(xlUp)(2, 1).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("CCX data SORTED").Select
    Range("Z1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SCMT Queue"
    Range("Z2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-25],'SCMT Daily Drop'!C[-16]:C[-14],3,FALSE)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Z2:Z5000")
    Range("AA1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Days Since First Approved"
    Range("AA2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'SCMT weekly data'!C7:C34,27,FALSE)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA2:AA5000")
    Range("AB1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Still Parked"
    Range("AB2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'SCMT weekly data'!C7:C34,28,FALSE)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2:AB5000")
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A55000").End(xlUp)(2, 1).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("SCMT weekly data").Select
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets(Array("SCMT weekly data", "SCMT Daily Drop", "CCX data SORTED")).Select
    Sheets("CCX data SORTED").Activate
    Sheets(Array("SCMT weekly data", "SCMT Daily Drop", "CCX data SORTED")).Copy
    Windows("SCMT Parked.xls").Activate
    Sheets("SCMT weekly data").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Sheets("SCMT Daily Drop").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Sheets("CCX data SORTED").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    MsgBox ("Macro Complete")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want it? IF you want it in the z column, for example, try:

```
Columns("Z:Z").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("Z1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "New formula"
Range("Z2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AA2-AB2"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Z2:Z5000")
```

I don't understand the formula you need, but there's a template you can use... If you give us the formula we can put it the second last line?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your quick reply.
Im looking at creating the column in AJ for eg. and same as the formula used for "Days since 1st authed less parked" 

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(COUNTA(RC[-21],R2C34)=2,NETWORKDAYS(RC[-21],R2C34,'Bank hols'!RC[-31]:R[56]C[-31]),"""")"
        Range("AG2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-1]),SUM(RC[-1]-(RC[-3]+RC[-7])),"""")"
        Range("AG1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Days since 1st Auth less parked"

thanks again

Comment: OK, so simply replace my "Z" with your "AJ", and the =AA2-AB2 with the equivalent line from higher up the program , and you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks again, will this calculate correctly and impliment network days

Comment: I know that this is the formula for working out the network days since it was first authorised - "=IF(COUNTA(RC[-21],R2C34)=2,NETWORKDAYS(RC[-21],R2C34,'Bank hols'!RC[-31]:R[56]C[-31]),"""")"
 - however im not sure where its pulling the column data from since i cant understand its referencing. i understand its using a tab on the work book which has dates for bank holidays, but unsure which columns its pulling from to run the formula and calculations.

Comment: you should almost NEVER use Select your code will be much better as `Columns("Z:Z").Insert
Range("Z1").Value = "New formula"
With Range("Z2")  .FormulaR1C1 = "=AA2-AB2"
   .AutoFill Range("Z2:Z5000") End With`

Comment: Cool i'll bare that in mind when i get better at vba, still learning and the previous guy well. Any way. does anyone understand the formula i posted?